# Osx Sierra argument list too long

Tags: macos, list, arguments

I'm facing this kind of error:

`zsh: argument list too long: [command]`

I need to launch a command via terminal that needs as argument a long string (it's about 1.4mb).
So instead of copy-paste the string into the terminal I actually save it on a file and then I take the content with `cat file.txt`.
So the command I launch in the end is:

`bitcoin-cli -rpcconnect=127.0.0.1 -rpcport=16593 -rpcuser=root -rpcpassword=root submitblock 'cat test.txt'`

(where ' symbols before and after `cat test.txt` are `)

This, as I said before, leads me to the error `zsh: argument list too long: bitcoin-cli`.

I've already tried to follow this blog post:

[Link](https://blog.dekstroza.io/ulimit-shenanigans-on-osx-el-capitan/)

Even if it changed the setting returned by `ulimit -a`, it didn't solve my issue.

Does anyone knows a solution? 
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of a command is defined by the `kern.argmax` sysctl setting, which is not changeable. On my system (El Capitan) it's 256kB:

```
$ sysctl kern.argmax
kern.argmax: 262144
```

So I don't think you'll be able to specify your block on the command line. Maybe there's the possibility to load it from a file or from standard input?